# How to protect bash function from being overridden? Make it readonly

Tags: bash

In the `bash` shell, we can define a function `f` with

```bash
f(){ echo Hello; }
```

and then redeclare/override it, without any error or warning messages, with

```bash
f(){ echo Bye; }
```

I believe there is a way to protect functions from being overridden in this way.

Comment: the same as with variables, with `typeset -r`: `typeset -rf f`.

Comment: or `readonly -f f`

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You may declare a function `foo` as a read-only function using `readonly -f foo` or `declare -g -r -f foo` (`readonly` is equivalent to `declare -g -r`).  It's the `-f` option to these built-in utilities that makes them act on `foo` as the name of a function, rather than on the variable `foo`.

```
$ foo () { echo Hello; }
$ readonly -f foo
$ foo () { echo Bye; }
bash: foo: readonly function
$ unset -f foo
bash: unset: foo: cannot unset: readonly function
$ foo
Hello
```

As you can see, making the function read-only not only protects it from getting overridden, but also protects it from being unset (removed completely).

---

Currently (as of `bash-5.0.11`), trying to modify a read-only function would not terminate the shell if one is using the `errexit` shell option (`set -e`).  Chet, the `bash` maintainer, [says that this is an oversight](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-bash/2019-10/msg00000.html) and that it will be changed with the next release.

Update: This was fixed during October 2019 for `bash-5.1-alpha`, so any `bash` release 5.1 or later would exit properly if an attempt to modify a read-only function is made while the `errexit` shell option is active.

Comment: Attempt to override function produces message `bash: f: readonly function` and non-zero status code, but does not exit if `errexit` option enabled.

Comment: @kyb I noticed this as well. I'm not certain it's a bug in `bash`, but I will ask on one of the `bash` mailing lists to be sure.

Comment: good, please update your answer when you will be sure about this behavior.

Comment: @kyb Both Stephane Chazelas and Greg Wooledge weighed in on that question, both with plausible explanations. Stephane suggests that `bash` only exits when `set -e` is in effect when POSIX _requires_ it to (and `readonly -f` is not POSIX). Greg points out that the `bash` manual never mentions "failure in function declaration" as reason for `errexit` to trigger an exit (unless a function declaration counts as a compound command, which he's pretty sure it does not). The thread is ongoing here: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-bash/2019-09/msg00039.html

Comment: @kyb I'm also noticing that you never say anything about `errexit` or `set -e` in your question.

Comment: thank you for investigation.

Comment: @kyb Chet (the `bash` maintainer) says it's an oversight and that it will be fixed in the next release of the shell (so that changing a read-only function trigger the termination of the shell when using `set -e`). https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-bash/2019-10/msg00000.html

Answer (score 1):

Little remark to @Kusalananda's answer. According to what bash maintainer said that changing a read-only function shall trigger the termination of the shell when using `set -e`.

I'm using Ubuntu 20.10 with a much newer bash version. Unfortunately it seems to be broken.

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 5.0.17(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

test.sh

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -e

test() {
    echo "I'm test() function"
}
readonly -f test

test

test() { # should exit here
    echo "I'm test() function (duplicated)"
}
test
```

Output

```
$ chmod +x test.sh; ./test.sh
I'm test() function
./test.sh: line 14: test: readonly function
I'm test() function
```

I've tested this script inside a docker container using latest bash version and it works as expected.

```
GNU bash, version 5.1.8(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-musl)
```

Comment: Thank you for updating this thread